# R: loop exercise without NAs on output

Tags: r

I am practicing a simple R loop. From a vector "m" with values 1 to 20, i want to create a loop that save a selected value in a object"a" and the remaining values in object "b".

This is what i did:

```
a=NULL
b=NULL

m <- c(1:20)

for (i in m) 
     if (i == 4){
      a[[i]] <- i
     } else {
      b[[i]] <- i
     }
```

This is the output:

```
> a
[1] NA NA NA  4

>  b
[1]  1  2  3 NA  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

My question is: how can i improve my loop code so the output does not show NAs, and without using function "na.omit"?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at your loop. On the first iteration, `i = 1`, you assign the value to `b`. But on which index? Next, on `i = 2`, you again assign the value to `b`, but which index do you use this time?

Comment: Have a look at `a[length(a)+1] <- i`

Comment: BTW, a fundamental design feature of R is minimizing the use of explicit loops altogether:  For example `m <- 1:20, a <- m[m ==4], b <- m[m!=4]` gives you what you want.  Using the the base R vector, base R apply and the tidyverse collections of functions will make your code much more manageable.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=NULL
b=NULL

m <- c(1:20)

for (i in m){
  if (i == 4){
    a <- i
  } else {
    b <- append(b, i)
  }
}
```

This will put a single value (in this case 4) in object `a`, and will consecutively add the other values to `b`.

Result:

```
> a
[1] 4
> b
 [1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve it is with vector operations. We doesn't need to do a loop to solve some problems about classification.

In your case, we can use:

```
    m = c(1:20)
    subset_with = m[m == 4] # It returns the values with the maching (m == 4)
    subset_without = m[m != 4] # It returns the values with the maching (m != 4)
```

I hope this helps you.